# Problem in Custom Paging with ASP.NET 2.0 GridView

Tags: gridview, custompaging

I have a Database table containing product information as follows:
ProductID, KeywordID, ProductDescription

and there are some keywords stored in a Keyword table as 
Keyword ID, KeywordDescription

I have to show a paged report for products on a page containing the gridview and a combo box - The Keyword is selected in a combo box and the Gridview shows paged information for the Keyword. Obviously I cannot use the rowid approach to implement paging here because all the products related to different keywords are in the same table.

Can someone suggest a good solution.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I did this one myself after googling for it: 
I created a synthetic RowID which is a continuous number using following SQL portion:

"ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ) AS ResultSetRowNumber"

To be honest, I lost track of the post which helped me achieve this. I will post the link soon as I find it.